# How to download/upload Azure B2C TrustFrameworkPolicy using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am looking for some documentation where I can learn how can I download Azure B2C TrustFrameworkPolicy using Java.

I went through a lot of documentation but I am not able to find out how.

What I think is :

1. Do we have to create a restful webservice and I hit some endpoint with some header parameter to make a download of the XML file, if so can someone share the endpoint, what input params we will need.
2. Or, do we have an pre written API (like graph api) and we need to create a clientprovider and a graph client using clientID, b2cTenantID and clientSecret which we can use to download the XML policy.

If someone may, suggest an approach, or share a link or any use study material, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is broken at the moment...

Instead use this...

```
     ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = 
             new ClientCredentialProvider(clientId,
                     scopes,
                     clientSecret,
                     b2cTenantId,
                     endpoint); 
    
     OkHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault(authProvider);
     Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/policies/B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients/$value").build();
     Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
     System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

This will give you the XML you need which is nothing but the policy.